# validate if a list contains at least one value from a set

Tags: java, list, set

I'm trying to verify if my list `myList` getName() contains at least one value of a set `names`.
I created a method for it, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way in Java.

```
private boolean validateMyList(List<myObject> myList, Set<String> names) {
   for(myObject obj : myList) {
      if(names.contains(obj.getName())) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Please define _simpler way_.

Comment: I guess you are hunting for some shorter code, such as `return myList.stream().anyMatch(obj -> names.contains(obj.getName()))`?

Comment: Sidenote: Types in Java should be declared with an uppercase letter. So, it should be `MyObject`, not `myObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return myList.stream()            // Stream<myObject>
    .map(myOject::getName)        // Stream<String>
    .anyMatch(names::contains);   // boolean
```

That is a Stream solution, though not necessarily faster.